# How to generate CNN model with changing frames in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to build a conditional CNN model in Tensorflow, but I met some trouble with it.

Suppose there is a matrix named ***features*** with shape [64, ?, 50, 1] and another matrix named ***conditions*** with shape [64, ?, 1, 130].

The fisrt dim is the batch size, and the second dim in means the frame number (**the value in this dim of the two matrices is same in each batch, but different in different batchs**). The third one is the feature dimention, and the last dim is channel num.

I want to concat the two matrix, which means we can get a matrix with shape [64, ?, 50, 131], and do ***conv2d*** in tensorflow.

But the problem is that I cannot concat these two matrices because of the difference in the third dim. Then I did as follows:

```
    x_shapes = x.get_shape()
    y_shapes = y.get_shape()
    return tf.concat(3, [x, y*tf.ones([x_shapes[0], x_shapes[1], x_shapes[2], y_shapes[3]])])
```

But it doesn't work because the second dim is not known.

I wonder is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not clear from your question, it looks like you want to broadcast the second tensor with shape `[64, ?, 1, 130]` on the 3rd dimension, the one you call feature dimension, before you concatenate. Note that `tf.concat` needs all the dimensions to match, except the one along which you are concatenating. From the documentation of [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#concat) :

> The number of dimensions of the input tensors must match, and all
>   dimensions except concat_dim must be equal.

To do the broadcast along the feature dimension, it is much cheaper to use  [`tf.tile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining#tile) instead of multiplying with a all ones tensor like you are doing. Here is how you would use `tf.tile` :

```
tf.concat(3, [x, tf.tile(y, [1, 1, x_shapes.as_list()[2], 1])])
```

In your case, since the 3rd dimension of `y` is known statically, the above code works. If that's not the case, you can form the second argument to `tf.tile` as follows :

```
tf.tile(y, tf.concat(0, [[1], [1], tf.shape(x)[2:3], [1]]))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply because of the chinese new years. Many thanks for your kind reply, and your answer works very well. Thanks again!